# Selecting of students under restraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations

> A delegation of $4$ students is to be selected from $12$ students. In how many ways can the delegation be selected if $2$ particular students wish to be together and other $2$ wish not to be together in the delegation?

A B wish to be together C D not together.

---

My attempt:

- CASE$1$

A B are included (remaining $10$, $2$ to choose), C is included D excluded: $\binom11\times\binom81$

- CASE$2$

A B are included (remaining $10, 2$ to choose), D is included C excluded:$\binom11\times\binom81$

- CASE$3$

A B are both excluded(remaining $10, 4$ to choose), C is included D excluded: $\binom11\times\binom94$

- CASE$4$

A B are both excluded (remaining $10, 4$ to choose), D is included C excluded: $\binom11\times\binom93$

---

**Edit**

- CASE$5$

A B are both excluded(remaining $10, 4$ to choose), D is excluded C excluded: $\binom11\times\binom84$

- CASE$6$

A B are both included(remaining $10, 2$ to choose), D is excluded C excluded: $\binom11\times\binom82$

- **Total:** $324$

This apparently gave the wrong answer and I feel I've done a mistake in selecting. I don't know which case is extra.

Comment: You haven't counted the case in which none of the four people are selected for the delegation.

Comment: Nor have you counted the case in which AB are included but CD both are excluded. Look at it like this -- for CD, we have three cases: C incl, D excl; C excl, D incl; C excl, D excl. For AB, we have two cases: AB incl, AB excl. This makes a total of $2\times3=6$ cases.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri now extra cases are being included answer is 216

Comment: @Anusha Look at the last part of [this question](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-delegation-of-4-students-is-to-be-selected-from-a-total-12-students-in/). The correct answer is indeed $226$ and not $216$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the cases you were missing, your answers for case $3$ and $4$ are wrong. AB are excluded and either one of CD is included. So out of the remaining $8$ students, you want to select $3$. This will give you the correct answer of $226$.